# Android Studio falsely marks conditionals as always true

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.0

I have a class that's intended to be subclassed. There's a variable and a method that looks at the variable:

```
protected int base = 10;

private void rebuildDisplay() {
    if (base == 10) {
        dealWithBase10YadaYada(X);
    } else {
        dealWithOtherBase(X, base);
    }
}
```

Android Studio flags the `if (base == 10)` statement with `Condition 'base == 10' is always 'true'`.

But here's the thing: even though `base` is always 10 *in my class*, my subclass will be changing `base` to other values. So `base == 10` *isn't* always true.

Is there a way to tell AS to not make assumptions about protected or public variables? Should I disable this test entirely, and if so, how? Heck, should I be reporting a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue (not a bug) because it goes against encapsulation and ties your class implementation to that variable. Say there was a more efficient way to do whatever you wanted without using base; You can't change your code because users rely on base, and it would break code.

A setBase() method could have it's inner workings changed if you ever needed needed them to.

There is probably a lint setting you can change.

Comment: So basically, sharing protected variables with subclasses is a bad idea in general? I can see the logic behind that. I suppose a setBase() method could be added easily enough. I've already made a couple dozen changes to my app to make Android Studio happy. (Porting from Eclipse was *not* an easy task.)